# Hibernate remove relation manyToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have 3 tables Role, User, and UserRole. The table UserRole contains the mapping between user and role along with the two corresponding index columns. I am using hibernate with annotations, and would like to be able to "Revoke" a role from the user, but this is turning out to be somewhat difficult.

In my User Class I have

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, targetEntity = Role.class)
    @IndexColumn(name = "role_index", base = 0)
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinTable(name = "tblUser_Role", joinColumns={
    @JoinColumn(name = "UID")}, inverseJoinColumns={
    @JoinColumn(name = "roleid", nullable = false)})
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>(0);
```

In my Role class I have

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, mappedBy="roles")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(0);
```

and the DAO method I am calling to "Revoke" the role(s) is

```
@Override
    public boolean revokeRolesFromUserAccount(User user, List<Role> userRoles) {
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info("Roles revoked from the User " + user.getUsername());
        }
        if (user == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (userRoles == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Iterator<Role> iter = userRoles.iterator();
        List<Role> newroles = new ArrayList<Role>(0);
        Role role = null;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            role = (Role) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                    Role.class, iter.next().getRoleid());
            newroles.add(role);
        }

        User newUser = null;
        newUser = (User) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(User.class, user.getUid());
        newUser.getRoles().removeAll(newroles);
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(newUser);
        return true;

    }
```

for some reason this does not work as expected, when breaking through I noticed the roles were not being initialized I guess due to the LazyLoading, and I tried doing something like `Hibernate.initialize(newUser.getRoles())` but this did not change anything. I am still learning the ropes with hibernate and am not sure what I am missing, maybe something very obvious?? Thank you so much for your time and thoughts in advance!

UPDATE: After trying the fixes suggested by Paujo and Matin Kh and doing further debugging I still have not seen any differences in the Roles being loaded in after line `newUser = (User) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(User.class, user.getUid());`

Here is a copy of my tblUser_Role, not sure if this helps. Thanks again!

**(Adding roles works just fine)**

[image]

Comment: Adding `@Transactional` to `revokeRolesFromUserAccount` should take care of problems with LazyLoading. Dou you get an exception when calling `revokeRolesFromUserAccount`? When you debug this line `newUser.getRoles().removeAll(newroles);`, are there any roles on the user?

Comment: Thank you for the response! This did not seem to fix the EAGER loading problem. When debugging it seems the roles are still not loaded into newUser just after line `newUser = (User) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(User.class, user.getUid());`. (I also made the change that Matin Kh suggested and added `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` onto my `List<User>` in `Role` Any additional thoughts would be greatly appreciated! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working, mostly by sheer luck, this is what I ended up with in my RoleDaoImpl class.

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean revokeRolesFromUserAccount(User user, List<Role> userRoles) {        
        if (user == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (userRoles == null) {
            return false;
        }   

        User newUser = null;
        newUser = (User) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(User.class, user.getUid());   

        List<Role> newRoleList = newUser.getRoles();

        newRoleList.removeAll(userRoles);

        if(newUser.getRoles().retainAll(newRoleList)){
            if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
                log.info("Roles revoked from the User " + user.getUsername());
            }
            this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(newUser);          
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
    }
```

Hope this can be of some use to others in the future!

Thanks again for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact situation here. Your question has a very simple solution.

For one of your classes use `EAGER`, and for the other one use `LAZY`. Try this:

Role:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, mappedBy="roles")
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(0);
```

User:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, targetEntity = Role.class)
@IndexColumn(name = "role_index", base = 0)
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinTable(name = "tblUser_Role", joinColumns={
@JoinColumn(name = "UID")}, inverseJoinColumns={
@JoinColumn(name = "roleid", nullable = false)})
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This did not seem to fix the EAGER loading problem. When debugging it seems the roles are still not loaded into newUser just after line `newUser = (User) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(User.class, user.getUid());`. Any additional thoughts would be greatly appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: I have tried setting `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` on both User and Role, and this did not seem to make a difference either.

Comment: I'd give it another try and I'll inform you about the outcome.

Comment: Alright thank you! I have been fooling with this all day and cant seem to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach should be different.

UserRole should have a role name.

Your User should have a list of UserRole items or just one UserRole but with a hierarchy of UserRole. But as you have a list that is ok.

So basically you have references in User to UserRole so there is no need to have references to User in UserRole.

That way your table becomes very simple and you dont need any joins to do it and you can then just select UserRole by name.

After that you should be able to remove the reference from the list of UserRole in User and merge the User.